# Can i set a custom uid in firebase anonymous auth with java?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am authenticating anonymously to access firebase but I would like the self-assigned UID to be according to a standard that I have defined, then I leave the anonymous authentication code I use:

```
auth.signInAnonymously()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {


                mUsername = idChat.substring(0, 10);
                id = task.getResult()
                        .getUser()
                        .getUid();
                isLoggedIn = true;
                mPhotoUrl = "";
                initAdapter();
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(task -> displayError(task.getMessage()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. You can use `Firebase Anonymous Authentication` to create and use temporary anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. Note, that if an anonymous user decides to sign up to your app later, you can link their sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue to work with their protected data in future sessions.

Users are identifiable by the same Firebase `user ID` regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in (`Anonymous Authentication`, `User/Password`, `Google account`, `Facebook account` and so on).

So the custom id is generated by Firebase and there is no possibility to set a custom uid as in your terms.

Comment: oh! ok i change my authentication or create a backend to use a custom token, Ty @Alex

Comment: Actually, you can, it just requires some effort with Firebase, not sure if it worth it.