# Can I set custom UID when using signInWithPhoneNumber of Firebase Auth in javascript when user first logs in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want document-ids of user database to be their phoneNumber+userName. For that purpose I want to set custom UID for the user when he first logs in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control the UIDs generated by Firebase's built-in providers. If you want to control the UID, you will have to create your own provider. I'd recommend against using any part of the credentials as the UID though, as you want a UID to be stable and not have to change it when someone gets (for example) a new phone number, or wants to be known by a different user name.

This has been covered a few times before, so I recommend also checking out:

- [how to create FireBase new users with custom UID with flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71132883/how-to-create-firebase-new-users-with-custom-uid-with-flutter)
- [Custom UID for each user created for Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022292/custom-uid-for-each-user-created-for-firestore)
- [Create users with custom uid as key with React Native Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874684/create-users-with-custom-uid-as-key-with-react-native-firebase)
- [Can i set a custom uid in firebase anonymous auth with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432060/can-i-set-a-custom-uid-in-firebase-anonymous-auth-with-java)
- and more of these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+custom+uid)